# C# Automatically assign property based on other property values

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

If I have some types e.g:

```
public class SomeType //Generated by some codegen i won't to change that.
{
    string C { get; set; }        
}

public class AnotherType : SomeType
{
    string A { get; set; }
    string B { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to assign property C automatically? For example when properties A and B get assigned or when I am Casting this type to some another type, or somehow else?

Basically for example I want to execute some logic to automatically assign property C according to values A and B at some point when properties values A and B get populated.

Is there any another ways of doing that rather than using standard properties?

I was thinking that it is possible to do some king of magic when i may cast type AnotherType to SomeType, but i cant implement implicit operator where i may put this conversion logic "from A+B to C"  because compiler doesn't allow implicit operator for related types.

Now Only way i see it is remove inheritance and implement implicit operator for AnotherType to SomeType conversion, but the evil in that case i need to duplicate all properties of type SomeType within type AnotherType and i need to change type AnotherType manually every time when SomeType getting changed.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is possible using auto-implemented properties. You could use the setter of B to assign a value to C:

```
public class SomeType
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    private string _b;
    public string B 
    { 
        get { return _b; } 
        set 
        { 
            // Set B to some new value
            _b = value; 

            // Assign C
            C = string.Format("B has been set to {0}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have inheritance i cant modify properties

Comment: You are not modifying the names or the types of the properties, just the implementation of their getter and setter which should not break your inheritance.

Comment: @bigb: I'm confused as to your comments.  Are you saying that A & B, and possibly C, are auto properties inside of a class you are inheriting and can't modify?

Comment: that would only be true if the properties are virtual (which is, of course, not the default).

Answer (score 14):

Do you want to be able to set C, or just get it? If you don't need to be able to set the value, then I think you want this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private string _a = "not set";
    private string _b = "not set";

    public string A
    {
        get { return _a; }
        set { _a = value; }
    }

    public string B
    {
        get { return _b; }
        set { _b = value; }
    }

    public string C
    {
        get
        {
            if (_a != "not set" && _b != "not set")
                return "not set";
            else
                return "set";
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a simpler example of accessing a property that is dependent on another property:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private double[] MyArray = new double[5];

    public int NumElements
    {
        get
        {
            return MyArray.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I only need to "get" the variable, and it always made sense to me to put this kind of logic on the variable that is being automatically changed anyway, since theoretically the affecting property (`A` or `B`) could maybe affect many many other variables

Comment: In the case where MyArray is a List<object> populated from a database. how can we guarantee NumElements is initiate calculated after MyArray is populated? is it based on the order the properties are listed?

Answer (score 5):

Not that I know of, you'd have to use bog standard properties as follows (incase you only know about automatic properties)

```
public class SomeType
{
    string _A;
    string _B;
    string _C;

    public string A { get{return _A;}  set{ _A = value; _C = _A + _B; } }
    public string B { get{return _B;} set{ _B = value; _C = _A + _B; }
    public string C { get{return _C}; }
}
```

Comment: i cant use standard properties

Comment: @bigb, autoimplemented properties **are** standard properties. They are just syntactic sugar that gets compiled into standard properties, so yes **you can use** standard properties, you already do.

Comment: With your updated question I feel it has been answered. C can stay an auto, A & B which appear to be in your control can be standard properties which update C. You can't do it with auto properties however